# Confused about type casting in java

Tags: java, casting, linked-list

I am new to java and reading a tutorial that instructs me to use a string-cast to assign a value from `LinkedList` to a String object.

```
List l1 = new LinkedList();
l1.add("Michael");
String s1 = (String) l1.get(0);
```

But I did a type test and `l1.get(0)` reported as a String type:

```
System.out.println(l1.get(0).getClass());

Result: 
class java.lang.String
```

So I don't understand why the result of `l1.get(0)` has a type of `String` but I still need to type-cast it as a String in order to assign same to String variable.

Comment: the runtime knows, the compiler doesnt!

Comment: Because you did not specify any type when declaring your list thus the compiler have no idea which types reside in your list hence forcing you to manually cast them at retrieval. Declare your list as follow : `List<String> l1 = new LinkedList<>();` and you won't have to specify cast anymore as it will be done automatically. You might want to read about generics for a better understanding.

Comment: the java compiler requires the cast because of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety#Java

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't think that this is the OP's issue - it looks like he doesn't understand the difference between static and actual types in Java. Need to find a more helpful duplicate.

Comment: the questing was `I don't understand why the result of l1.get(0) has a type of String but I still need to type-cast it` and the answer is Type Safety. i think the duplicate explains that pretty well